# Why is Language Learning a different blue from other beta sites?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

I just noticed a difference in the blue of the Language Learning Stack Exchange to all other beta Stack Exchange sites I have in my list.

> [image]

I presume, this is a (minor) design bug, isn't it?

I have visited both links, therefore it should not be a difference between visited and unvisited links in the browser. The browser is Mozilla Firefox 58.0.2 on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS.

EDIT: As of just now, I see in the hot questions list two other beta sites featuring the blue of Language Learning, namely IPS and cse. The following sites currently feature the blue of Open Data: W, PCO, Ph, P, ME, Mv, SX, BG, and RC.

EDIT 2: The small icons occurring in the Top Questions view and in the sidebar hot questions are all of the same blue as the Open Data logo.

Comment: Hrm, It does not appear that way on any of my screen(s). Windows 10 Chrome/Firefox; iPad Safari/Chrome; MacBook OSX Safari/Chrome; iPhone Safari

Comment: Ah ... I want to add the following fact: I have a brand new operating system with a clean firefox (no cache content anywhere)

Comment: Norepro with Mozilla Firefox 58.0.2 on Arch Linux for me.

Comment: Visited link isn't relevant, it is an image. What do you see when browing [directly to the image](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/languagelearning/img/icon-48.png)?

Comment: Do you mean the links or the icons? The icons do look a slightly different blue to me on my phone. Could be a gamma issue?

Comment: It's the icons that have a clearly different blue for me.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see the LL icon in the same blue as in the screenshot.

Comment: Well... that's something really weird, but on your side. Maybe OS, maybe browser... no idea.